# How to write native query in Doctrine / Postgres equivalent to a normal PDO_PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query in php with (pdo_pgsql) adapter:

```
$dsn = "pgsql:host=$host;port=5432;dbname=$db;user=$username;password=$password";
$conn = new PDO($dsn);
$query = 'SET search_path TO xyz_de;';
$result = $conn->query($query);

$query = 'Select * FROM "Orders" WHERE vendor_id=189 ';
$statement = $conn->query($query);

while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    var_dump($row); // --> working perfectly fine, I see results here
}
```

I want to reproduce it using doctrine so I'm doing the following:

```
// given: 1) $this->em = EntityManager
// 2) the conenction is established successfull (I debugged it and sure about it)
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery("SET search_path TO xyz_de ", $rsm);
$query->execute();

$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT * FROM "Orders" WHERE vendor_id=?', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, 189);

$orders = $query->getArrayResult();
var_dump($orders); // Gives empty array (no errors)
```

as per my comment in the last line, the problem is that I get no results and no errors when using doctrine for this

Comment: I clarified it, already had a comment in the last line of code,

Comment: Did you change the log what query it actually executes?

Comment: the query from debugging is identical to the native query using the pdo_pgsql driver directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things:

1. You can use [`addScalarResult`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#scalar-results)

A simple example:

```
$rsm->addScalarResult('my_real_column', 'my_alias_column');
$query = $this->em->createNativeQuery('SELECT my_real_column FROM "Orders"');
var_dump($query->getScalarResult());
```

2. But I think, the best you can do is to use the [queryBuilder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#working-with-querybuilder).

Comment: queryBuilder has a lot of issues with pgsql

Comment: The problem was the mapping actually, But please correct your answer:
getArrayResult  works perfectly fine

Comment: Okay exact in https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/8625ca5187c05dbf5b4bfb3b3725f7c806e0644a/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L737-L740

Comment: @Shehabix : I use postgres with queryBuilder and I have no problem.

Comment: Query builder has an issue with doctrine in case of case sensitive tables (which is my case) and we have read-only access to db, so can't really change it ..